# Qt Get signal-slot connection information from a widget

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a feeling this isn't possible with the current API, but I have to ask.  Is it possible to query a particular QObject's signal or slot name (from the metaObject) and retrieve all the QObjects and their slot or signals names that are connected to it?

I'm doing this because, in effect, I have a large number of layouts that contain an identical arrangement of widgets, for each layout there an object and each of the layout's widgets control the various properties of it.  I want to keep one layout, and connect it's widgets' signal/slots to all the other objects in the same pattern, but in order to do this I need to 'record' all the signal-slot data.

Is it possible?

Comment: sounds like a short-cut to lots of headache. Have you considered just moving out all the necessary connect-statements to a function?

Comment: It's not that simple.  I have a 'Properties' panel, that displays the properties of selected objects, each object is in an inheritance chain and each class in the chain provides a UI in a layout (and the appropriate connections) for the properties the class manages.  These layouts are chained together to produce the final layout that put into the properties panel.

Comment: However, if multiple objects of differing types are selected, the properties that are common between them are picked out and assembled into a layout.  So far, so implemented.  But each object has it's own signal-slot connections, these need to be moved into the newly created layout, so I have one layout controlling many objects.  This requires me to query and record the signal-slot connections of the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting file in Qt - `%Qtdir%/src/corelib/kernel/qobject_p.h`, it contains class `QObjectPrivate`, used by Qt internally. 
Use 
`static QObjectPrivate *get(QObject *o)` function to get QObjectPrivate member for your widgets, and try to call its interesting members like
`QObjectList receiverList(const char *signal) const;` or `QObjectList senderList() const;`. File is totally undocumented, but it seems to contain exactly what you need...

Comment: Great investigating, but I can't see how I can use it because it is a private class (Qt uses PIMPL for nearly all the classes), so I will have to copy the source code into my project which undoubtedly raises licensing issues.

Comment: Begs the question: why didn't they include that functionality into the public API?  It's useful!

Comment: really, this class is not private, it is just undocumented. it is declared as `class Q_CORE_EXPORT QObjectPrivate : public QObjectData` - so you do not need to copy any source, it is being exported from QtCore dll

Comment: Also, if you afraid of warning "that file may change without notice" there is another fact about qt - their libraries are binary compatible with previous versions. That means that no exported functions and classes will be removed until qt5 will arrive.

Comment: Only patch releases are binary forward and backward compatible, minor releases are only backward binary compatible. So switching from Qt 4.6 to 4.7 may break your software. But switching from 4.6.3 to 4.6.4 won't

Comment: 4.6 to 4.7 WON'T break, that is backward compatibility as is)
but 4.7 to 4.6 may break, because forward compatibility is not guaranteed.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have to debug or extend code written by others, and when I set a breakpoint inside a slot, it is very difficult to find out which signal was sent from which class. It would be nice to be able to have a listing of all connects in your code: at the moment I can one search manually through the source code.